# How to retrieve data/key:value pairs from URL-encoded form using POST in express/node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, body-parser

I have a html from that have 4 input fields. Form is configured like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="alert('data submittet')">
```

So, it should default to  x-www-form-urlencoded.
The form is working, and i can submit my data.

On the server/node.js side i have the following configration and code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));


app.post("/", function (req, res, next) {

console.log(req.body);

console.log(req.body.var1);
console.log(typeof(req.body.var1));
});
```

What i get from this is is the actual values in curly braces in my console window:

```
{ var1: '123456', text1: 'oiu', text2: 'abc', text3: 'def' }
```

But i can not console.log the individual parameters as they are 'undefined' and i do not understand how to get these values so i can use them in the code on the server side. Am i missing some parser, setting or why should this not be working?

Comment: what does req.body['var1'] return?

Comment: What do you mean? As in a element: console.log(req.body[0]) .......Or as in a key: console.log(req.body.var1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh gee. It was just to store the req.body data in a variable :S

```
app.post("/", function (req, res, next) { 
console.log(req.body); 
var receiveddata = req.body; 
console.log(receiveddata.var1); 
})
```